# How to translate a simple target pattern rule to snakemake?

Tags: snakemake

I'm looking for a way to define a target pattern rule (without input pattern) in Snakemake.

In this case, I want a rule that creates the files `a`, `b` and `c` as part of a pattern on the target file where the input does not contain a pattern.

In GNU make, I would do it like this:

```
.PHONY: all
all: a b c

%:
    echo x > $@
```

However, if I do the following in Snakemake:

```
rule test:
    output:
        "{filename}"
    wildcard_constraints:
        filename = "[abc]"
    shell:
        "echo x > {filename}"
```

> WorkflowError: Target rules may not contain wildcards. Please specify concrete files or a rule without wildcards.

I can of course specify the `output` using an `expand()` call, but that would imply that the rule creates all files when called once, which is not the case. Rather, it should create *one* file when executing `shell` with a certain argument (`{filename}` in the example here).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your GNU Make code. The target pattern you are trying to exemplify is "all: a b c" where all is the target and "a b c" is the pattern yes?

Comment: I'm looking for a rule to generate a single file whose name contains a wild card when the input does not have a wildcard pattern. That's exactly what the Makefile says: construct a pattern from no pattern. In this particular case, the rule can be used to create files with any name and content `x`. The target files are `a`, `b` and `c`, which are all created by calling the pattern rule three times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tims answer below basically contains the solution. But since you have asked me on Twitter, let me directly translate your Makefile:

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand("{filename}", filename=["a", "b", "c"])

rule test:
    output:
        "{filename}"
    wildcard_constraints:
        filename = "[abc]"
    shell:
        "echo x > {filename}"
```

All these basics are explained in the [Snakemake tutorial](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/basics.html#step-7-adding-a-target-rule).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, at the point when I pinged there was no answer, and I was genuinely confused because the tutorial (that you link) has no output wildcards without input wildcards. Maybe the error message can be improved? After all, this is a (valid) target rule that contains a wildcard.

Comment: Yes, the error message could indeed be improved. Target rules may not contain wildcards. Otherwise, Snakemake would not know how to fill them.

Comment: s/wildcard/pattern/ in my comment; sorry for the imprecise use

Comment: In newer versions of Snakemake, `shell: "echo x > {wildcards.filename}"`

Answer (score 1):

**The issue is {input} versus {wildcards.namedVar} access in the shell directive.** [See here in the documentation](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snakefiles/rules.html#wildcards). With that said, I do not see your driver call for the Snakemake setup, which I would also recommend. (I've added it in my answer below). It would be equivalent to the .PHONY and all rule pattern (the messy convention that GNU Make forced us into).

**In your shell directive, the variable {filename} is accessible as an attribute of the wildcard object. You need to use python dot notation to access it, like {wildcards.filename}.** With that said, the better way would be to directly access the input wildcard object because it actually has built in toString conversion, since it carries only a *single* list of strings (where as the wildcard object can contain *multiple* individual wildcard attributes, so the behaviour is not predictable).

You can ignore the ".snk" suffix, I just think it's nice for Snakemake rule files. In code, this is what I mean:

**test.snk**

```
 rule test:
     output:
         "{filename}"
     wildcard_constraints:
         filename = "[abc]"
     shell:
         "echo x > {wildcards.filename}"
```

In identical fashion, you can also do this, **test.snk:**

```
 rule test:
     output:
         "{filename}"
     wildcard_constraints:
         filename = "[abc]"
     shell:
         "echo x > {output}"
```

## Recommended Code Base:

**test1.snk:**

```
 rule test:
     output:
         "{filename}"
     wildcard_constraints:
         filename = "[abc]"
     shell:
         "echo x > {output}"
```

**Snakefile:**

```
 configfile: "config.yaml"

 rule all:
     input:
         expand("{sample}", sample=config["fileName"])

 include: "test1.snk"
```

**config.yaml**

```
fileName: ['a','b','c']
```

**$snakemake -n:**

```
 rule test:
     output: a
     jobid: 1
     wildcards: filename=a


 rule test:
     output: c
     jobid: 2
     wildcards: filename=c


 rule test:
     output: b
     jobid: 3
     wildcards: filename=b


 localrule all:
     input: a, b, c
     jobid: 0

 Job counts:
     count   jobs
     1   all
     3   test
     4
```

## Additional info

Also, this setup scales VERY well :) Run it just using the CLI call Snakemake, absent of any arguments. Like:

```
 snakemake
```

Although this is terrible practice, technically it's also possible if you are more "outcome" oriented, and don't care about reproducibility.

```
 snakemake -n -s "test1.snk" a b c
```

That will essentially target just rule "test1.snk" and request from it "a", "b", and "c".

```
rule test:
    output: c
    jobid: 0
    wildcards: filename=c


rule test:
    output: b
    jobid: 1
    wildcards: filename=b


rule test:
    output: a
    jobid: 2
    wildcards: filename=a

Job counts:
        count   jobs
        3       test
        3
```

You can see the dry-run call is actually different, as it is not accessing the "rule all", as a result, there is no 4th job. Overall the processing by Snakemake is usually trivial to the processing performed by shell commands. With out without an "all" rule I would expect very little difference in performance. Yet, with the all rule, it's infinitely clearer what your code is suppose to be doing, and you can easily re-run the exact same command without having to 'grep' your 'history'.